# Regex to validate a username in react native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, validation

I don't know much regex and when it comes to username it becomes a little tricky, so I request  from my fellow programmers to help me validate a username with respect to certain conditions.

1. Username can only contain letters, numbers, periods and underscores.
2. Username can start and end with underscores but never with periods. (for security reasons)
3. Username length should be between 4 and 20 characters.
4. Spaces are not allowed

***Examples of valid and invalid usernames:***

josh `valid`

.josh_ `invalid`

_josh. `invalid`

_josh_123.brad `valid`

josh brad `invalid`

I have already searched and the answer I find didn't quite help. This is my regex for now:

```
RegExp('^(?=[A-Za-z0-9._]{4,20}$)[^_.].*[^_.]');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved without any lookahead:

```
/^\w[\w.]{2,18}\w$/
```

If you want to use `RegExp` then use:

```
var re = new RegExp("^\\w[\\w.]{2,18}\\w$");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXk6ig/1)

**Pattern Details:**

- `\w`: is a shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `^`: Start
- `\w`: Match a word character
- `[\w.]{2,18}`: Match 2 to 18 counts of word or dot characters thus making total length between 4 to 20
- `\w`: Match a word character
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks man, that worked like a charm. Unfortunately, I need more reps to upvote your answer. Anyway, thanks